# Looping through an array N times

Tags: c

I'm wondering if its possible to loop through an array N times, stop do some work then loop through it N more times.

I'm thinking that it involves a nested loop structure but I'm not really sure how you would go about structuring it.

Comment: If you want to parse an array more then once, then you need separate loops, not two nested loops. Please show what you have tried, with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Not very clear. Is that a single array of N elements of an array of any size processed N times?  Perhaps a less abstract description is required.

Comment: Is it required to iterate the array just twice `50-work-50` as stated or indefinitely `50-work-50-work-50 ...`, as might be interpreted by your suggestion of nested loops?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to count the iterations and on every 50th, the the "work":

```
int count = 0 ;
for(;;)
{
     // do xxxx on array element on every iteration
     xxxx(  array[count] ) ;

     if( count == N - 1 )
     {
         count = 0 ;

         // Do yyyy this every N iterations
         yyyy() ;
     }

     count++ ;
}
```

An alternative interpretation of your question:

```
int count = 0 ;
for(;;)
{
     // Process whole array on every iteration
     for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array); i++ )
     {
         xxxx( array[i] ) ;
     }

     if( count == N - 1 )
     {
         count = 0 ;

         // Do yyyy this every N iterations
         yyyy() ;
     }

     count++ ;
}
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop, since your `for()` has no condition in it.

Comment: Why are you using `for()` if you don't put anything into the header of the loop? Why not `for (count = 0; ; count++)`?

Comment: @Barmar : You could do that.  I chose not to.  I regard modification of a for loop control variable other than in the `for()` a practice best avoided.  In this simple example  it may not matter but in more complex code it may not be obvious to a maintainer what is happening.  You could I suppose have `for( count = 0; ; count = (count == N-1) ?  0 : count + 1 )`, but that is hardly clear and just a perverse way of avoiding a coding rule.  `while(true)` is another option, but I have used compilers for which that idiom generated a warning, so this idiom is now my habit.

Comment: It is an infinite loop since I interpreted the question as iterating indefinitely.  That may not be the case.  I have asked for clarification in a comment.

Comment: I didn't notice the `count = 0;` statement in the middle of the loop, so I didn't realize you were modifying the iteration variable outside the loop control. I also don't interpret the question as asking for an infinite loop. It just says loop N times, then loop another N times.